# how to get the duration of an audio file after uploading using FFMPEG

Tags: .net, asp.net, ffmpeg

I am uploading audio files in asp.net using FFMPEG.My question is how can i get the duration of the file(in seconds).

Please suggest me.

Thanks and Regards
Srinivas M

Answer (score 9):

Why do you want to parse the output? Instead use FFMpeg APIs to get duration from the audio stream of file. One cannot rely on output strings, say the development team decides to change logs in future. So use APIs to get the duration.

Follow these steps:

```
1.  av_register_all();

2.  AVFormatContext * inAudioFormat = NULL;
    inAudioFormat = avformat_alloc_context();
    int errorCode = av_open_input_file(& inAudioFormat, "your_audio_file_path", NULL, 0, NULL);

3.  int numberOfStreams = inAudioFormat->nb_streams;
    AVStream *audioStream = NULL;
    for (int i=0; i<numberOfStreams; i++)
    {
        AVStream *st = inAudioFormat->streams[i];

        if (st->codec->codec_type == CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO)
        {
            audioStream = st;
            break;
        }
    }

4.  double divideFactor;
    divideFactor = (double)1/rationalToDouble(audioStream->time_base);

5.  double durationOfAudio = (double) audioStream->duration / divideFactor;

6.  av_close_input_file(inAudioFormat);
```

I havent included any error checks in this code, you can work it out for yourself. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do and it works great for me.  Call

```
ffmpeg -i District9.mov
```

Then find the length of the video in the below snippet with a regex or a simple `string.startWith("       Duration:")` type check:

```
Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 5994.00 
(5994/1) -> 29.97 (30000/1001)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/stu/Movies/District9.mov':
  Duration: 00:02:32.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9808 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264, yuv420p, 1920x1056, 29.97tbr, 2997tbn, 5994tbc
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16
    Stream #0.2(eng): Data: tmcd / 0x64636D74
```

You'll should be able to consistently and safely find `Duration: hh:mm:ss.nn` and parse it to determine the source video clip size.